# Player that can fade out/in a song

Tags: windows, software-rec, media-player

Organizing some party soon, and I need some player that can fade out after a song has been played for 2 minutes, and then fade in a new one (I'm not sure "fade" is the offician term - down volume the previous song, and slowly up volume the next one).

Anyone knows of any ?

Edit: Just to clarify - I need something that will jump to a next song after this one has been playing for two minutes (regardless of its length), and something that will fade out and then in (which I already have enough suggestions - trying the winamp plugin now).

Platform: WinXP

Comment: why would you do that? say, you happen to have Bohemian Rhapsody in your playlist and the bloody thing fades out after 2 minutes, somewhat of a showstopper, isn't it? that could cause mayhem and get you subjected to some serious abuse! :D

Comment: and the way you describe it, you don't even want CROSS-fading, as in mixing the start of the next song with the end of previous song.

Comment: It's a dance party /half of the things don't even have lyrics/... we're not gonna listen to the Queen. And yes, I want exactly cross fading - just not from the end of the song, but from what's currently at the two minutes mark, to the start of the next thing in the playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1900?viewlocale=en_US) and [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) support Crossfade, but this will not automatically occur after 2 min.

Edit: foobar2000 with the [Preview component](http://skipyrich.com/wiki/Foobar2000:Preview) supports 2 minute (or whatever) previews, but crossfading no longer works.

Edit 2: In foobar2000's preferences, if you change `Advanced > Playback > Fading > Fade out` to 2000 ms (or your desired fade time) then crossfading will work, with the 2 minute preview.

Comment: @sblair - excellent !! exactly what was called for !

Answer (score 2):

Download Winamp and install this plugin: [SqrSoft Advanced Crossfading Output](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/sqrsoft-advanced-crossfading-output/32368)

It works great.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what platform. 3rd-ing Winamp on Windows. Not sure about Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) is great!

To do change the cross-fading time segment, go to:
Tools | Options | Player | Output Plugins | MM DirectSound Output | Configure

Comment: If you want IO addons, check out: http://www.mediamonkey.com/addons/input-output/